# Call function in another function with global variable in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I cannot get the response value form the called function in the caller function.

I tried to pass a request body for the API call form "customerGet" function to "callAPI". "CallAPI" function hits the backend and brings the response. When I log the response in the "callAPI" function I can see the data is coming correctly. But in "customerGet" function the response is not coming at all. NOTE:- both function are in the same controller.

```
private function callAPI(){
        logger($this->data);
        $response = Http::withHeaders($this->headers)
            ->asForm()
            ->withoutVerifying()
            ->post(config('config.be_api'), $this->data);

        $json = json_decode($response, true);
        logger($json);
        return $json;

    }
  
public function customerGet($customerId)
    {
        $this->data['CRequest'] = "<Call1>CustomerGet</Call1><Key>$customerId</Key>";
        
        logger($this->callAPI($this->data));
        return $this->callAPI($this->data);
    }
```

Comment: Just a note, `callApi()` doesn't accept any parameters, so `$this->callAPI($this->data)` is invalid. `$this->callAPI()` is the correct call.

Comment: I tried that too but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using json_decode, try to return raw response, then in `customerGet` method use `json` method from `Http` class:

```
private function callAPI(){
    logger($this->data);
    $response = Http::withHeaders($this->headers)
        ->asForm()
        ->withoutVerifying()
        ->post(config('config.be_api'), $this->data);

    logger($response);
    return $response; //return raw response
}

public function customerGet($customerId)
{
    $this->data['CRequest'] = "<Call1>CustomerGet</Call1><Key>$customerId</Key>";

    $response = $this->callAPI($this->data);
    logger($response->body());
    return $response->json(); //output in json using Http classs method json()
}
```

Comment: I need the properly decoded php json version of the raw data because the data coming is a json string and complicated. Then I will assign it another instance.